# Tweepy in python 2.7 Auth for streamlistener, receives error 401 as response

Tags: python-2.7, tweepy

I am new to streaming tweets using the tweetpy I followed the examples, found here that explain that I need to obtain keys from tweeters. I did so and used this code to establish a connection for this streamListener. However, I only get an "Error:401". Any ideas are welcome! Thanks!

```
from slistener import SListener
import time, tweepy, sys

CONSUMER_KEY       = '' 
CONSUMER_SECRET    = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN        = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''


OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':CONSUMER_KEY, 'consumer_secret':CONSUMER_SECRET,
 'access_token_key':OAUTH_TOKEN, 'access_token_secret':OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET}

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])
api = tweepy.API(auth)

def main():
    track = ['#Matthew', '#HurricaneMatthew']

    listen = SListener(api, 'myprefix')
    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listen)

    print "Streaming started..."

    try: 
        stream.filter(track = track, languages=['en'])
    except:
        print "error!"
        stream.disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the code to work changing this lines in the program. with the insight found in other posts.

```
# OAuth process, using the keys and tokens
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

# Creation of the actual interface, using authentication
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```